# I have a data in google spreadsheet dates are in horizantal form, I want to convert like vertical form with dates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[my data is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcgoW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzzjd.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=arrayformula({A1:B1,"Date",C2:E2;{
regexreplace(query(split(flatten(split(flatten(query(transpose(query(if(C1:H1<>"",char(9998)&" "&substitute(A3:A," ",char(9999))&" "&substitute(B3:B," ",char(9999))&" "&C1:H1&" ",)&C3:H,"where Col2 !=''",0)),"",9^9)),char(9998)))," "),"select Col1,Col2 where Col1 !='' order by Col3",0),char(9999)," "),
query(split(flatten(split(flatten(query(transpose(query(if(C1:H1<>"",char(9998)&" "&substitute(A3:A," ",char(9999))&" "&substitute(B3:B," ",char(9999))&" "&C1:H1&" ",)&C3:H,"where Col2 !=''",0)),"",9^9)),char(9998)))," "),"select Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6 where Col1 !='' order by Col3",0)}
})
```

Within the formula, amend the ranges:

`C1:H1` - change `H` to match your end range (keep #1)

`C3:H` - change `H` to match your end range

[image]

The formula is a little more complex than it needs to be to work with potential spaces in the Vendor and Client names whilst ensuring that numbers are formatted as numbers (not text).

A simpler formula to switch spaces to `-` would be:

```
=arrayformula({A1:B1,"Date",C2:E2;query(split(flatten(split(flatten(query(transpose(query(if(C1:H1<>"",char(9998)&" "&substitute(A3:A," ","-")&" "&substitute(B3:B," ","-")&" "&C1:H1&" ",)&C3:H,"where Col2 !=''",0)),"",9^9)),char(9998)))," "),"where Col1 !='' order by Col3",0)})
```

If you never have spaces in Vendor or Client name, then even simpler is:

```
=arrayformula({A1:B1,"Date",C2:E2;query(split(flatten(split(flatten(query(transpose(query(if(C1:H1<>"",char(9998)&" "&A3:A&" "&B3:B&" "&C1:H1&" ",)&C3:H,"where Col2 !=''",0)),"",9^9)),char(9998)))," "),"where Col1 !='' order by Col3",0)
})
```

Comment: Thank you Very much Aresvik for quick response on my question. It will try it

Comment: =arrayformula({A1:B1,"Date",C2:E2;query(split(flatten(split(flatten(query(transpose(query(if(C1:H1<>"",char(9998)&" "&substitute(A3:A," ","-")&" "&substitute(B3:B," ","-")&" "&C1:H1&" ",)&C3:H,"where Col2 !=''",0)),"",9^9)),char(9998)))," "),"where Col1 !='' order by Col3",0)})

Comment: This formula was working , but i don't want to substitute space with hyphen"-".

Comment: I gave you three options. If you have spaces in Vendor or Client names, then use the first formula. If not, use the third one.

Comment: Hi , Pls help me out for this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71647184/i-have-dates-in-text-like-mar-26-mar-27-in-excel-i-need-dates-from-the-text?noredirect=1#comment126624002_71647184